# NSubstitute ambiguous call when following documentation example (but with async method)

Tags: c#, asynchronous, nsubstitute

So I tried copying an example about exception throwing from the documentation, and added this to one of my methods:

```
.Returns( x => { throw new Exception(); });
```

But this results in the following compiler error:

> Error CS0121  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or
>   properties: 'SubstituteExtensions.Returns(T, Func,
>   params Func[])' and
>   'SubstituteExtensions.Returns(Task, Func, params
>   Func[])'

The method I'm using is an async method. I tried awaiting the method first, but that returns a different error, saying that it

> can not return value of type X for  (expected type Task`1)

UPDATE:
I can change the lambda in the returns to be async as a way to get around the compiler error, but this results in a warning. So I guess the question now is more about whether or not there's a way to bypass this without having the warning show up, and without adding needless await code inside the lambda itself?

Is there a way to avoid this? I'm using NSubstitute 2.0.3

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The compiler error in your question looks like you are calling something that returns `Task` rather than `Task<T>`? This sample works for me:

```
public interface ISample {
    Task DoStuff(string name);
}

[Test]
public async Task SampleTest()
{
    var sample = Substitute.For<ISample>();
    sample.DoStuff("test").Returns(x => { throw new Exception("doh"); });
    // ...
}
```

I tend to get that error when I have a generic `Task<T>`, which can be fixed by specifying the return type in the `.Returns()` call like this:

```
public interface IRepository {
    Task<int> FindId(string name);
}

[Test]
public async Task SampleTest2()
{
    var sample = Substitute.For<IRepository>();
    sample.FindId("test").Returns<int>(x => { throw new Exception("doh"); });
    // ...
}
```

In the example above I've removed the ambiguity by using `.Returns<int>(...)` which will pick the first overload mentioned in the compiler error.

If that does not help could you post the signature of the method being tested?

Comment: Can you add the information to NSubstitute documentation? I've hit the same problem second time. 
Or consider  some name changes to avoid ambiguity?

Comment: I fell over this issue too.  I think updating the NSubstitute documentation to help people trying to throw errors when returning from `Task<>` would be a tremendous help.  Something like the answer from @m12lrpv would be fabulous.

Answer (score 5):

Adding to Davids accepted answer if you want the Task method because your method does actually return a Task then you simply need to specify `Returns<Task>`.

```
object.Method().Returns<Task>(x => { throw new Exception("You messed up"); });
```

It's not necessary to specify the full return type i.e. don't do this -> `Task<IEnumerable<YourClass>>`